# A step in the proof of Atiyah exercise 3.21 i)

Tags: commutative-algebra

The exercise is

> Let $A$ is a ring, $S$ a multiplicatively closed subset of $A$, and $\phi:A \rightarrow S^{-1}A $ the canonical homomorphism. Show $\phi^{*}:\operatorname{Spec}(S^{-1}A)\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is a homeomorphism from $\operatorname{Spec}(S^{-1}A)$ onto its image in $X=Spec(A)$

I have proved that $\phi^{*}$ is injective ,and since $\phi^{*}$ is continuous ,then it is enough to prove $\phi^{*}$ is closed map or open map. And I want to prove it is a closed map. Suppose $\alpha $ is an ideal of $S^{-1}A$ ,then we know $\overline{\phi^{*}(V(\alpha))}=V(\alpha^{\mathrm c})$. So it is enough to prove ${\phi^{*}(V(\alpha))}=V(\alpha^{\mathrm c})$. And

$p\in \phi^{*}(V(\alpha))\Leftrightarrow \ \exists q\in V(\alpha)$,such that $p=\phi^{*}(q)$ $\Leftrightarrow \exists\, q,\alpha \subseteq q,p=q^{\mathrm c}\Rightarrow \alpha^{\mathrm c}\subseteq p$

But I cannot prove that $ \exists\, q,\alpha \subseteq q,\,p=q^{\mathrm c}\Leftarrow \alpha^{\mathrm c}\subseteq p$. And even I think it is may be not true.

Are there mistakes in my proof ?

Comment: Oh , I just make a stupid mistake and I have know the answer.

Comment: In general this map will not be closed. For example, let $A$ be $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ and $S=\{1,x,x^2,...\}$. Then the spectrum of $S^{-1}A$ is essentially just the points in the plane that don't lie on the $y$ axis. This is clearly an open set but not a closed one.

Comment: Technically, you do not want to prove that $\phi^*$ is closed (or open), as in "the image of a closed set is closed": you want (and need) to prove that it is closed *onto its image*; in other words "the image of a closed set is closed in the relative topology of the range of $\phi^*$".